# What's "The Elephant King" setting inspired by?

Tags: story-identification, inspiration

It's pretty clear that [Storium's](https://storium.com/) pre-made settings are firmly rooted in specific popular works: "The Mysterious Island" is "Lost;" "Steampunk" is heavily inspired by the *Dinotopia* franchise; "Medical Drama" looks a heckuvalot like "House MD" to me.

But I'm not familiar enough with post-colonial fantasy to recognise the origins of "The Elephant King." It's a post-colonial fantasy Africa where the colonisers have rescinded control of the land and the locals face the task of rebuilding and reclaiming their own nation:

> Explore a fantastical realm brimming with magic, monsters, and adventure! Foreign paladins of the Distant North have left the lands of the Elephant King, after years of mining and trade, to fight amongst themselves. They left behind a handful of castles and knights to maintain relations with the local populace but these forests, mountains, plains, and cities have long belonged to the Elephant King and it is time to take back the realm.

The Elephant King setting has shamans, honourable thieves (one in particular named "Shadowcat"), wizards, and a history of dragons (but none anymore). Knights are called "Sair" instead of "Sir," though I have no idea if that's a Storium-specific conceit.

Does this seem similar enough to any existing works that a case for inspiration could be made?

Comment: I would be inclined to look toward Haggard's Allen Quatermain books, the most famous of which was *King Solomon's Mine*. That said, those books don't really match up with "post-colonial" in any way. There's a whole genre of "post-colonial" literature out there, but most of it is semi-historical and/or allegorical.

Comment: @SeanDuggan If there's something more than "white men in a semi-supernatural Africa" which makes Quatermain a match (I think *Tarzan* and *Tintin* would qualify too, if that was sufficient), I think it would be worth a full answer to explore.